# SET NAMES command fails with access denied

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to insert an accented `e` into a mysql database following [this example](http://xaviesteve.com/1223/issues-with-accents-and-strange-characters-in-php-mysql-solved/). Using this:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

throws:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'

Its not connecting to the database:

```
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'user');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'pword');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'test1');
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: The error says `mysql_error` and your query uses `mysqli_connect` -- is there something fishy?

Comment: AHHHH Thankyou, how stupid of me. Doesnt solve the issue of saving and e accent into my DB but solves the issue i asked about the connection. Thankyou. Just wondering if you know , it now saves the accent e and a black traingle with a ? in the middle, know why/how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried any of the other things listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through , such as saving PHP files as UTF-8 ([without BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)) and setting an "accept-charset" on any forms? If so, ask a separate question.

Comment: Thankyou again. Setting the php file to UTf-8 seemed to work. Thankyou

Comment: Using `@` to suppress errors is usually a bad plan as well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Setting the `php file` to `UTf-8` seemed to work.

Answer (score 9):

Don't mix use of the `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. Instead of

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

use

```
$dbc->set_charset('utf8');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no problem in connection there is the the problem that you are using the `mysql_query` and you are connecting with `mysqli_connect`.

So use the `mysqli_query` to execute the query.

Comment: Yes thankyou, Amal Murali already hinted to me this, but thankyou aswell.

Comment: For the latest information please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.set-charset.html  it tells us the procedural and object oriented ways of conencting and changing to UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'pword');
mysql_select_db('test1',$dbc);
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"',$dbc);
```